# issue witch 2.4.2 configurable product

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.4, popup

I created a new attribute 'Format' which allows me to choose between '1' / 'pack of 3' / 'pack of 6'
Then I created a configurable product with 3 virtual products.

It works well,
BUT
the only issue is that Magento (or theme ?) is showing me a popup giving me the product ID and I have to click on "OK".

How to make this popup disappear?

The URL is: https://www.axodiet.com

Product is only visible through search: axotest.

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by disabling a modified js from custom module.